# Google sheets pivot table - display totals at the top

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table, google-sheets-formula

Is that possible to change pivot table totals row location in Google Sheets so that they display directly under the pivot headers?
I have browsed the available options and tried googling but no answer.

Comment: I don't know how to move totals to the top, but if this pivot table is not very complicated, it's possible to workaround with standard formulas and then you have much more flexibility. Also if you want to use TOTAL for referencing somewhere, you set a cell which takes maximum value where total should be. Lets say =Max(c3:c) (total is always bigger that other cells :-) ).

Comment: Thank you and dzięki both of you! I feel I will use your hacks sooner or later. It is also clear for me now that it is really no built in option to control location of total row. BTW - what I did was simply copy-pasting my pivot table and simply removing Rows entry from the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another Workaround is, to create another Pivot-Table on top and delete the Rows.
Greetings

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly how I ended up (please see my comment under the init question). Greetings, Jakub

Answer (score 2):

This article describes a couple of ways to extract totals from a pivot table, either the whole row, or individual columns.  This should let you build a "Totals" row on top of (above) where you are displaying the pivot table.

[Formula to Extract the Total Rows From a Pivot Table](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/extract-total-and-grand-total-rows-from-a-pivot-table/)

Comment: Thanks and please see my answer above.